# Passing on the parameters of a function into another one?

Tags: python, function, variables, parameters

I'm not really sure how to word this, but I'll try my best. I've created a function for a zombie, and another one for attacks. But I don't know how to pass on the parameters of the zombie function into the attack function. Also if there is a more technical way to word this please let me know. Here is my test code for it, I'm sure this community will be able to figure out what I mean. The end goal is to create a function where I can plug in a monster name and have it's assigned parameters (health, defense, etc..) be run in through the combat function. ie def `combat(monster_name):` Any and all advice is much appreciated. Thank you!

```
#Functions
def zombie():
    global  zombie_hp
    zombie_hp = 10
    print "Zombie encounter"
    print "Current Health:", zombie_hp
def attack(monster):
     if monster > 0:
        while  monster > 0:
            user_action = raw_input("Do you attack the zombie? [y]: ")  
            if user_action == "y":
                monster_hp = monster_hp  - 1 
                print "Health remaining: ", monster_hp

def user_action():
    global user_action
    user_action = raw_input("Do you attack the zombie? [y]: ")




# Zombie Encounter (attack_testing)
attack(zombie())
if zombie_hp == 0:
    print "Zombie Defeated"
```

Comment: What if you defined the attack function inside of the zombie function? That way the attack function would have access to the scope of its outer function, the zombie function.

Comment: A rule of thumb: when your thing is a noun, it should probably be a Class. When your thing is a verb, it should be a function. Here, you want a Class Zombie() that contains a function attack(self, ...)

Comment: Well, I think I need to look into classes now. Learning this one line at a time, and trying to implement each new thing I learn.

Comment: just return the result of one function as an input to another function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you use a `class`:

```
class Zombie:
    def __init__(self):
            self.defense = 10
            self.hp = 100
    def hit(self, hp):
            self.hp-=hp
    def upgrade(self, level):
            self.defense+=level
```

This will remember the hp and defense for every zombie that you create

```
>>> Max = Zombie()
>>> Max.hit(17)
>>> Max.upgrade(2)
>>> Max.hp
83
>>> Max.defense
12
>>>
```

Comment: When I create a zombie class, how do I have it effected by combat?

Comment: You can use the `hit()` method. You can have the user press a key to strike, and cause a random amount of damage.

Comment: Max might be the worst possible name you could have chosen for the zombie, lol.